# KeyError while trying to plot a pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot-table

I build a pivot_table out of a dataframe to get numbers distribution between years across states:

```
data['issue_d'] = pd.to_datetime(data['issue_d'])
data['issue_year'] = data['issue_d'].dt.year
data_table_years = data.pivot_table(data,index='addr_state', columns='issue_year')['loan_amnt']
```

And it gives me nice outcome:

```
issue_year       2007.0     2008.0      2009.0      2010.0      2011.0
addr_state                  
AK               nan        12,300.00   12,480.56   10,666.67   13,975.98
AL               6,855.56   9,986.25    8,787.95    9,850.96    12,841.84
AR               2,533.33   9,018.75    10,479.17   9,892.19    10,848.63
```

But when I try to build a lines plot out of it it will build the plot but the Series are the issue_year (I need the addr_state instead so that issue years are on the X axis)

But when I try to `.plot(x='addr_state')` I get `KeyError: 'addr_state'`

Is there a way to set the plot to use the right Series?

Comment: since `addr_state` is the index of `data_table_years` have you tried `.plot(x=data_table_years.index)` ?

Comment: yes, it will draw series by year, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you transpose it?:

```
data_table_years.T.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't know you could transpose it this way :)